# How to find camera pose for rigid objects of an image given 3D points in local coordinate system?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, pattern-recognition, pose-estimation

Given image points and corresponding 3D points of 7 objects in an image (all objects in their local coordinate system) how can I find camera pose for each of the objects. Some hint that is given to solve this problem is that we need to find transformation matrix which transform points in the respective local object coordinate systems to the global coordinate systems.

Comment: So you have all the objects in a single image? Do you know internal camera parameters? Is the global coordinate system defined or can be arbitrary?

Comment: Yes the image given is from Linemod dataset, where all the 7 images are given on single image. Yes, Internal camera parameters i.e. K is given but the global coordinate system is not defined. If we assume P=[I 0]T where T is the transformation matrix T= [R t;0 1] then P=[R t]. We can apply DLT to solve this. These are all the hints given to solve this problem. I have tried but I end up with big reprojection error.

Comment: Can you post this image and corresponding image and model points? Please also post the code that you used.